# AlarmManager doesn't work in library project

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I have an app that has a Alarm class. I seted to start up Alarm class by below code

```
AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent(CompassActivity.this, ir.aiga.apps.news.Alarm.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(CompassActivity.this, 0, i, 0);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 10000, pi);
```

When I use this project only it works correctly but when I mark this project as library and use it another project it is not work.

I have added the library manifest elements like permissions, activity an receiver declaraion in the main project manifest file.

What's problem ?

Answer (score 1):

you should register your Broadcastreceiver in the manifest of both your library and your project. something like this:

```
<receiver android:name="[your package name].[your broadcast receiver class]"/>
```

make sure to put both of them it under `<application></application>` tag. the code below is an example:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <receiver android:name="com.example.myapp.myreceivers.MyBroadCastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" >
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```